# SASL LOGIN authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism

Tags: email, postfix-mta, dovecot

I always get this error. I got default dovecot and postfix installed. Sending mail from Thunderbird and PHP pear mail works fine but if I the mail server in vbulletin 4 it gives me this error in the mail.log.

Part from my config file.

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
```

It also throws this error:

```
 Client host rejected: Access denied;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your sasl_path is incorrect.

You can try to add something like

```
smtpd_sasl_path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
```

to your configuration file.